# memory and depth (vs. breadth) of recursion in c

Tags: c, memory, recursion

I have two questions related to memory. First some background. I am a novice-intermediate c programmer.

I have written several different tree like data-structures with variable number of nodes at each level. One such structure, can have as its data a number of integer variables, which themselves are primary data for integer trees. I have written recursive functions for genrating trees with random numbers of nodes at different levels. I pass pointers to randomly generated integer trees as parameters for generating the main data-structure.

I have also written recursive code for operating on these tree structures, such as printing the tree. Just for my learning, I created queue and stack for my nodes and wrote iterative functions for in-order, pre-order and posr-order printing of the tree. I think, I am beginning to get the hang of it.

Now the question.

(a) I need to write other functions, which are obviously easy and clean if written using pure recursion. I can see how it could be written iteratively. It is not difficult, just tedious.  The maximum depth of my trees will be 3-5, however, the number of nodes at each level is large. It is my understanding, that every recursive call will store addresses on a stack. If the depth is large, it can run out of memory. But if the depth is shallow, the penalty (memory/speed) of using a recursive function may not be terrible.

Do people have recommendations on criteria for deciding if an iterative/recursive solution is preferable?? I have read various threads on the site about iterative soution, but could not find any thing that directly speaks to this issue.

(b) Second, question relates to requesting memory from the system. I know that some applications can request certain amount of memory. I am using mingw-gcc4.x with Netbeans IDE. How can I specify the maximum amount of memory that the program can use in debug / release mode? Or, does it depend solely on the available RAM and no explicit specification is necessary?!

Thanks in advance,

paras

~RT

Answer (score 3):

"The maximum depth of my trees will be 3-5"

This depth of recursion will not challenge the default stack size of any version of Windows, or any other system you'll ever see that doesn't have "Watch out! The stack is tiny!" plastered all over it. Most programs go a lot more than 3-5 calls deep, without involving any recursion at all.

So as long as your recursion only goes "down" your tree, not "across" its breadth, you're fine. Unless of course you're doing something really unusual like sticking an enormous array on the stack as a local variable.

Am I right that your (post-order) recursion looks something like this?

```
void doNode(struct node *n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n->num_nodes; ++i) {
        doNode(n->nodes[i]);
    }
    // do some work on this node
}
```

If so, then for 3-5 levels the only way it'll use a lot of stack is if it looks like this:

```
void doNode(struct node *n) {
    int myRidiculousArray[100*1000] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < n->num_nodes; ++i) {
        doNode(n->nodes[i]);
    }
    // do some work on this node, using myRidiculousArray
}
```

If you have millions of nodes, then there may be some performance gain to be had from avoiding the function call overhead per node. But write it the easy way first, and then come back and look at it later *if* you're ever desperate for a bit more performance. It's fairly rare for the overhead of a function call per node to be reason your code is slow - it does happen, but usually only after you've fixed a bunch of other, even worse, slowdowns.

Comment: Thanks, That was very helpful. So, far I have needed to use preorder. 

    process node 
    process subnodes

And, yes - no big arrays laying around each within function call :)

Answer (score 1):

If you write your function using [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) (provided you're compiling with optimization enabled) you won't run into problems with stack or memory space.

In the end you need to program your functions so *you* can understand them so do whatever is easier for you.

Comment: Tail recursion only helps reduce stack growth for tail calls. With trees, especially when the nodes have a large fan-out (splay? what's the term?), the tail calls will roughly be at most `1/fan-out` of the calls for pre-order and in-order traversal, and at most `depth` calls for post-order.

Answer (score 1):

Even an iterative implementation is a recursive algorithm if you're using a stack to store nodes; both use O(f) space, where "f" is a function that's "more" than a constant (c is O(f) but f is not O(1)). You might still wind up using less memory with the iterative version if the elements of your stack are smaller than a call-stack frame. If so, you can look into reducing the size of a call stack by using closures, assuming the language supports them.

Iterative algorithms will have O(1) space requirements. Even a recursive implementation can achieve this using tail calls, as Dashogun mentions.

Spend a little time trying to find an iterative algorithm. If you can't find one, I recommend going with the recursive implementation unless you know for certain that you need to handle a recursive structure that (these days) has a depth of at least 2<sup>13</sup>. For a binary tree, that's 2<sup>2<sup>13</sup></sup> nodes, which I very much doubt you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Recursion is not bad in itself. However if writing the iterative algo is close in complexity you should use the iterative one. Before commiting to a recursive algorithm some prerequisites apply:

-You should make sure that the recursion depth (and the local variables in the re-entrant functions) will not make you exceed the stack size. For the depth you mentioned used on Windows this would be a problem in very few cases. Additionally you can add a safety check on the height of the tree.

(b) If you are asking about the stack size: I see you use mingw, thus you probably build for Windows. The stack size in Windows is per thread. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774%28VS.85%29.aspx) how to setup your reserved and initially commited stack size.

If you are asking about heap memory allocation have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx). But the short story is that you can use all the memory the system can provide for heap allocations.